# NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got the code below to call a PHP script, for some reason it say that the connection is successful but it actually didn't call my script since I haven't received the email :-(

None of the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods get called.

Testing on iPhone 5.x device and Simulator.

Any suggestions/ideas? Thank you very much!

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/mail.php?subject=%@&to=%@&body=%@", subjectLine, toAddress, emailBody ];

NSLog(@"web service URL: %@", url);

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"connection: %@", [connection debugDescription]);
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connection succeeded");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
}
```

Comment: Try switching `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];` with     `NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];`

Comment: Try to log the `url` string and then check if it is correct. `NSLog(@"%@", url);` Implement the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` method and check the error.

Comment: I get an exception when I change it to NSMutableURLRequest line. The didFailWithError event doesn't fire at all, none of the methods from NSURLConnectionDelegate fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/mail.php?subject=%@&to=%@&body=%@", subjectLine, toAddress, emailBody ];

NSLog(@"web service URL: %@", url);

//add the following or something like
[url setString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

//modify the following    
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; 
NSLog(@"connection: %@", [connection debugDescription]);
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connection succeeded");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
}
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"connection: %@", connection)` would be fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet that you have some content in your email body that's not safe to send through the url

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/mail.php?subject=%@&to=%@&body=%@", subjectLine, toAddress, emailBody ];
```

So say your email body contains **&**, that would break the code you have.  You either need to escape the message body or send it through the request body instead of passing it through the URL.  I could be wrong, but I bet that's what it is.  Your code looks fine, I bet its the data ;)

Comment: I URL encoded it to generate: http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/mail.php?subject=Vosto%20Demo%20Food%20Order&body=test
and it still give issues

Comment: If you navigate to your URL in the browser it fails... gives a PHP error on line 6. http://www.lenniedevilliers.net/mail.php?subject=Vosto%20Demo%20Food%20Order&body=test  I'd get it working where you could test it with your browser first, then test your iOS code once you know it actually sends mail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the specific delegate functions for NSURLConnection?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    //NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did Fail");
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Did Finish");
    // Do something with responseData
}
```